# Date not converting properly in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to convert date from one format to another in PHP but I am having issue doing so. the month and day are properly converted but the year still adopt present year.

**20 Apr, 2007** - date I am trying to convert

**2021-04-20** - format converting to. Looking at the year, it gives 2021.

What I tried:

**Format 1:**

```
$date =  strtotime($_POST['dob']);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

**format 2:**

```
$idate=date_create($_POST['dob']);
echo date_format($idate,"Y-m-d")
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `date_create_from_format` instead

```
$date= "20 Apr, 2007";
$date= date_create_from_format('j F, Y', $date);
echo date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
```

output:

```
2007-04-20
```

You can read more about this function [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0):

2007 is also a valid [time format for DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php). With the comma in front of 2007 this is interpreted as 20:07 and the current year is taken as the year. A var_dump() shows that.

```
$date = date_create('20 Apr, 2007');
var_dump($date);
//object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2021-04-20 20:07:00.000000" ..
```

When interpreting date expressions freely, misunderstandings cannot be ruled out. A reliable interpretation can be achieved with the [date_create_from_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function.

```
$date= "20 Apr, 2007";
$date= date_create_from_format('!j M, Y', $date);
var_dump($date);
//object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2007-04-20 00:00:00.000000" ..
```

Note on ! in the format: Without that ! the current time is set for the DateTime object. This can lead to problems when using the result in calculations. With the ! all unnamed formats are reset, here the time to 00:00.